# Display 0x00-0x1F characters in font

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, ascii

I'm working on a tool that can edit the translatable strings file for some old DOS games.

The problem I'm facing is that I encounter ASCII characters in these strings that are in the 0x00 to 0x1F range (before the space). These characters have symbols in the DOS console font, but none of them seem to be present in any modern font.

This shows what I get (left) and what I want (right). The four shown entries contain respectively bytes 0x11, 0x10, 0x1E and 0x1F.

[image: the problem]

(Top part is a `DataGridView`, bottom part is a `TextBox`)

Is there an easy way to display them? I tried `new Font("Terminal", 8)` but that didn't work, and the font reverted to Microsoft Sans Serif. And neither the Lucida Console nor Courier New fonts contain these characters. I also tried `new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8)` (not sure exactly which font that results in) but that didn't have them either.

An additional problem is that I'm dealing with multiple regional DOS-based text encodings with special characters (there's a dropdown on the UI to switch instantly and reconvert from the backing bytes), so even if I would be able to switch to the console font, a lot of these special (Cyrillic, Greek, Arabic etc.) characters would probably not be available. The example entries show just one special character in one string, but in reality there could be combinations.

A possible alternative for the top part, since it's for display only, would be to do a substitution with unicode characters corresponding to the old DOS font (I'm already replacing the line breaks by U240D -> "␍"), but even then, I'm wondering if there's any automated way to pull that off.

Comment: Are you looking for these characters? ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼

Comment: Exactly. I... guess I could just copy them from your comment, lol

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yeah, that works... now I'm just stuck with the bottom part. The biggest annoyance is that some of them turn into zero-width characters... when making the mockup above I didn't even realize entries 41 and 42 in the file were also arrows, namely▲ and ▼.

Comment: That's not ASCII; It's CP437.

Comment: @TomBlodget Converting the 0x00-0x1F bytes using CP437 does _not_ give these symbols in the .Net framework. _That's the whole issue._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using a lookup table with `" ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼"` solved the first part of my issue; the preview in the `DataGridView` looks correct now. (thanks, [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei)).

As for the editing box, In the end I realized that my use case was contradictory; several of the extended-ascii encodings actually contain characters from that lookup table (mostly `•`, `¶` and `§`). I can't both use these characters for the 0x00-0x1F range, and also support encodings that contain some of them in their > 127 range.

So, instead, for the editable `TextBox`, I chose to use the unicode characters for the [C0 ASCII control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives)).

The change is purely visual; since I was already filtering the content of the `TextBox`, I ended up controlling and overriding all input methods; keyboard input, clipboard via shortcuts, and clipboard via context menu. And given the on-the-fly encoding switching system, I went right ahead and replaced the entire undo/redo system with my own, backed by the original byte arrays.

It may be a bit odd to use different characters for the preview and the editing, but as you can see from the mockup, the strings file clearly uses the symbols ◄, ►, ▲, ▼ to indicate left, right, up, down. That would be lost if I used the control code characters there as well.

One important compatibility note, though: I originally used the default MS Sans Serif font for this, which seemed to work on my Win10 laptop, but **it didn't work on my Win7 PC**, and gave substitute character rectangles for all the control codes. In the end I had to specifically switch everything (the `DataGridView`, the `TextBox`, and its context menus) to **Lucida Sans Unicode** to make it work.

---

The two functions `FilterText` and `FlattenText` are the core of the system. They use these three pieces of side data:

`ASCII_CONTROL` is a `const String` containing the ASCII control code characters: `"␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␉␊␋␌␍␎␏␐␑␒␓␔␕␖␗␘␙␚␛␜␝␞␟";`

`_validCharactersLowRange` is a `Char[]` containing the original 00-1F range of bytes converted to the selected text encoding. This is updated whenever the encoding is changed, though it seems to always just correspond to the unicode characters 00-1F, so not sure if it even needs to be updated. (As I said, this whole problem is more or less just the fact that fonts don't having proper symbols for that range.)

`_validCharacters` is another `Char[]` which contains the rest of this encoding's converted characters range, with the 00-1F range substituted with by the contents of `ASCII_CONTROL`, to get the full range of actual allowed characters in the editing `TextBox`.

The functions:

`FilterText` will filter out any input to characters to display in the `TextBox`. This includes replacing the 00-1F range with the ASCII control code characters. It is designed so that filtered text can be put through the same filter again without any problem.

Note that the use of `\r` as line break is part of the specs of the file format I'm editing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Filters illegal characters out of the given text, and converts
/// any characters in the 0x00-0x1F range to control code symbols.
/// Used for filtering file, keyboard and clipboard input.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Input text</param>
/// <returns>Text containing only normal ASCII characters, special > 127 characters of the chosen encoding, or control code characters for the 0x00-0x1F range</returns>
private String FilterText(String text)
{
    // Filter out null characters; they're completely illegal.
    Char[] inputch = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\r").Where(x => x != '\0').ToArray();
    // Make string for easy IndexOf lookup
    String validCharsLowRange = new String(_validCharactersLowRange);
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < inputch.Length; i++)
    {
        Char inputChar = inputch[i];
        // Ignore line breaks
        if (inputChar == '\r')
            continue;
        // Check for low range characters to replace
        Int32 index = validCharsLowRange.IndexOf(inputChar);
        if (index == -1)
            continue;
        inputch[i] = ASCII_CONTROL[index];
    }
    // Filter out illegal characters
    return new String(inputch.Where((x => x == '\r' || this._validCharacters.Contains(x))).ToArray()).Replace("\r", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

`FlattenText` takes the text from the `TextBox` and converts it to the bare characters expected in that text encoding, meaning the input is prepared for converting back to bytes, or for copying to the clipboard, It reverts the substitution of the 00-1F range with ASCII control code characters.

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert text from the input textBox to actual chars correpsonding to the chosen encoding.
/// This can be used for converting back to bytes; or for clipboard copy.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text from the TextBox.</param>
/// <returns>The normalized string.</returns>
private Char[] FlattenText(String text)
{
    Char[] preparedOutput = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\r").ToCharArray();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < preparedOutput.Length; i++)
    {
        Int32 index = ASCII_CONTROL.IndexOf(preparedOutput[i]);
        if (index != -1)
            preparedOutput[i] = this._validCharactersLowRange[index];
    }
    return preparedOutput;
}
```

---

Then, for good measure, I built in font size controls for the `TextBox`, because those control code characters are really freaking tiny... and added an easy way to insert them.

[image: final project]

(ignore the fact `0x0F` is missing; it's a small bug I fixed later)

Anyway, thanks for the help; I hope this convoluted mess can be useful to someone else. The full code can be found [here](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/project_stuff/2018/WWStringsEditor/dev/). Might be useful to anyone else trying to write something to handle these 00-1F characters. (Or, heck, someone writing their own undo/redo history system; got a pretty nifty one in there.)